# How do I set a custom SMS tone for a single contact in Android Messages running on Samsung Galaxy Note 8?

Tags: sms, ringtone, mms

[How do I set a custom SMS tone for a single contact?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/10519/how-do-i-set-a-custom-sms-tone-for-a-single-contact) in the answer at https://android.stackexchange.com/a/16653/13886 it is claimed that this option exists in the dot-dot-dot menu, but it does not for my phone.

[image: dot-dot-dot in Android Messages]

Was the feature there at some point, but then they took it out?

The phone is a Samsung Galaxy Note 8 running stock Android 8.0.0.

The Details button points to some central configuration that lacks adding a per-contact ring tone.

Is a specific app actually needed for this? Meaning, was this simply never built into Android? Or, is it there, but hidden by Samsung? Or  hopefully this is just user error, and I'm not finding the setting?

Comment: If you can't find it and everything leads to a dead end then yes it was probably removed. 3rd party app with the ability for custom sounds would be an alternative.